# TCP Socket frames 'queuing' up on Windows. How can I force each message in it's own frame?

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, tcp, air, websocket

I use Actionscript 3 TCP sockets to connect with Javascript websockets. Sending data is primarily from the websocket to the AS socket.

On Mac OS X, no problem. On Windows however, successive TCP messages seem to queue up somewhere. This causes the `ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA` event to fire with quite a large time interval, which creates noticeable lag.

I used Wireshark to monitor the TCP packets on both OS X and Windows. The difference I see is that on OS X each message comes in it's own packet, while on Windows successive messages are 'concatenated' into one packet.

Is this just the way the socket is implemented, or is there any way I can improve on this?

**EDIT 1:** [I found this post on actionscript.org which outlines the same problem](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=254422)

**EDIT 2:** I found a way to go around the problem. I pad every message with dummy text to increase the frame size. This causes the TCP stack to send every message in it's own frame instead if queuing them. This works, even though it's really, really ugly...

---

This is the code in the `SOCKET_DATA` event.

```
while(this.socket.bytesAvailable) {
    var byte:uint = this.socket.readUnsignedByte();
    if(byte == 0x00) {
        trace("Start byte found. - " + new Date().time);
        this.incomingMessageBytes = new ByteArray();
    } else if (byte == 0xFF) {
        trace("End byte found. Dispatching. - " + new Date().time);
        this.incomingMessageBytes.position = 0;
        var msg:String = incomingMessageBytes.readUTFBytes(incomingMessageBytes.bytesAvailable);
        var decodedMessage:Object = JSON.decode(msg, false);
        var message = new Message(decodedMessage.clientId, decodedMessage.command, decodedMessage.data);

        this.dispatchEvent(new MessageReceivedEvent(MessageReceivedEvent.RECEIVED_MESSAGE, message));
    } else {
        //trace("Appending.");
        this.incomingMessageBytes.writeByte(byte);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be not handling the socket properly. What socket protocol are you using? Are you flushing between each send from AS? Did post-pend a null character? How much data are you sending? Are you overlapping the data send requests

Comment: I'm using the websocket protocol (open with 0x00, close with 0xFF) using the regular Javascript API. The problem is not sending from AS to Javascript (although I haven't checked that yet, just didn't need that now), but the other way around. I tried throttling the data to every 20 milliseconds, but to no avail.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to make a handshake. client sends-> client waits for response-> client sends more-> client waits..... Make a class queue up your data sends?

Comment: Something like Wireshark will show you the network communication as it happens. That should tell you whether the bottleneck is on the client or the server side of the connection.

Comment: @The_asMan: Exactly. The handshake is no problem. Neither are 'individual' messages. The problem only arises when receiving multiple messages after each other.

Comment: @Joe Ward: Good suggestion, I'll try using Wireshark.

Comment: You know throttling to 20 milliseconds just doesn't seem to be enough to me. What kind of response time are you looking for? how long does say 10 queued up sends take?

Comment: I changed the throttle to 45 milliseconds, any higher and I find the response is too slow. I'm using it over LAN by the way. Also, I used Wireshark and I think I found something, please see the update :).

Comment: It sounds like you might be seeing the effects of Nagle's algorithm.  I don't know if there is a way to disable Nagle's algorithm (aka setting the TCP_NODELAY flag) under ActionScript, but if there is, you might try doing that.

Comment: Wow, that is exactly what I'm experiencing. Wikipedia even mentions "Interactions with real-time systems" as a possible problem. Thanks for giving the answer. I have a feeling there is no way to set the TCP_NODELAY flag in AS, but I'll look into it. In the meantime, I found I can bypass it by making my message large enough using some padding.

Comment: @Jeremy: If you post your command as an answer I'll be happy to mark this question as solved :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might be seeing the effects of Nagle's algorithm. I don't know if there is a way to disable Nagle's algorithm (aka setting the TCP_NODELAY flag) under ActionScript, but if there is, you might try doing that.